# How to index just selected json key using Django functionality instead of all keys?

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql, indexing

I have the next model:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb import KeyTextTransform
from django.contrib.postgres.indexes import GinIndex
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVectorField, SearchVector
from django.db import models


class ProfileUser(models.Model):
    name = JSONField()
    search_vector = SearchVectorField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [GinIndex(fields=["search_vector"], name="user_full_name_gin_idx")]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        ProfileUser.objects.filter(pk=self.pk).update(search_vector=SearchVector('name'))

        # I have tried this, but this does not work.
        # ProfileUser.objects.filter(pk=self.pk).update(search_vector=SearchVector(KeyTextTransform('name', 'name')))
```

And `name` looks like `[{'name': 'Random Name', 'lang': 'en'}, {'name': 'Какое-то Имя', 'lang': 'ru'}]`.

Currently the code above indexes both `name` and `lang` keys. Is it possible using Django to index just `name` key? I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48292735/django-postgres-how-to-create-an-index-on-a-jsonb-field) how to workaround this using SQL directly, but I just want to know, if it is possible to do that just via Django.

I use Django 2.2 and PostgreSQL 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Functional indexes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/3.2/#functional-indexes) is going to be available in Django 3.2 in April. This finally should allow to build needed indexes from Django.

Answer (score 2):

In PostgreSQL, the feature which allows creating indices on parts of a JSON-structured field is called [expression index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/indexes-expressional.html). It needs to be used together with [`GIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/textsearch-indexes.html) index to achieve the desired effect. Such a usage is briefly mentioned in the `jsonb` [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING):

```sql
CREATE INDEX idxgintags ON api USING GIN ((jdoc -> 'tags'));
```

To the best of my knowledge, currently (December 2020) the only way to create such an index in Django is to issue the SQL statements manually.

However, there is an open [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28928) which asks for adding the support for expression indices to Django. The feature has been accepted but there is no patch yet and the ticket has not been updated for more than a year.

Comment: Support was added in 3.2 in this PR:  https://github.com/django/django/pull/11929   However, I'm still confused on the proper syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, you can read the documentation for django indexing here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/indexes/

Change this line:

```
indexes = [GinIndex(fields=["search_vector"], name="user_full_name_gin_idx")]
```

to this:

```
indexes = [GinIndex(fields=["name"], name="user_full_name_gin_idx")]
```

Comment: This would not help, because `fields=["name"]` includes both fields (`name` and `lang`). `fields` means `field names of model` (not a key of JSON).